# In array, a[-1] shows consistency in behaviour?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int a[2];

a[-1] = -1;
cout << "Step 3 : a[-1] = " << a[-1] << endl;
    int mex = 0;
cout << "Step 4 : a[-1] = " << a[-1] << endl;
```

So I have an integer array `a` of size 2. When I access a[-1] its supposed to give me some random value each time I run the program. But in my program, it always assumes its value as 0. Here I change its value to -1. But in the output screen, it prints a[-1] as -1 in Step 3 and 0 in Step 4. When I try to do the same thing for a[100] this doesn't happen. Can you please explain what is happening here?

Comment: This is clearly undefined behavior. You are accessing the array outside of it's bounds so you get what you get.

Comment: You cannot rely on undefined behavior to give you random values. It's not guaranteed to be random and it's not even guaranteed to return a value. For example, it might crash or the line might be optimized out. Nobody can explain why it's doing what it's doing without inspecting the resulting assembly.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined and depends on compiler, system and moon phase. If you want explanations, learn assembly and examine the binary, or find someone that will do it for you.

Comment: *"Here I change its value to -1."* -- I don't see any such assignment going on.

Comment: Stomping over memory like that is a great way to cause your computer to catch on fire.

Comment: I can't seem to find this method of generating random numbers mentioned in any documentation.

Comment: You must have crashed your application few times, if not then your luck is still doing favor. Behaviour is undefined, anything can be at location which you are trying to access by `a[-1]`.

Comment: this might be a good time to compile your program using something like Asan

Comment: @tadman No need, the HCF opcode handles that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Since this is undefined behaviour, the compiler *could* emit a few of those just because.

Comment: @cdhowie changed it. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## In array, a[-1] shows consistency in behaviour?

Supposed `a` is a raw array of any type, dereferencing like

```
a[-1] = 0;
```

is out of the array bounds and exposes undefined behavior.

*Undefined behavior* includes giving **inconsistent** or **consistent** results (most probably because the implementation accesses arbitrary memory contents).

Comment: It's not even necessarily about accessing "arbitrary memory contents" but also about *optimization* -- since the compiler is permitted to assume that the behavior of the program is defined, if you do something that has undefined behavior, the optimizer is permitted to rewrite your code in ways that may not be obvious or even reasonable.

Comment: Why does it always give 0 as an output? Why can't I see different numbers each time I run the program like how it happens for a[100]?

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar `a[-1]` and `a[100]` are both out of bounds. The behavior of using either is undefined.

Comment: When your code can be proven to reach undefined behavior, you can't assume the result will even resemble what you wrote.

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar: Some numbers are more common in computer memory than others. And 0 is by far the most common of all.

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar Down that road lies madness, I think it's best you accept that this is a bad way of getting a random number

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar Undefined behavior is, by any mean, *undefined*. It may print `0` every time, it may crash, and it may erase your OS, and open a black hole in your living room.

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar Comparing two undefined behaviors is meaningless.  You might as well be comparing the statements "this statement is false" with "oogley boogley."  **Neither makes any sense even by themselves.**  Comparing them will yield nothing useful.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I agree to what you are saying. But isn't the probability of a[-1] being 0, 10 times in a row really low when it can be any integer?

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar there is no probability to discuss about, as this is not a random value. It's undefined.

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar _"But isn't the probability ..."_ The probability is low, because you have a specific stack layout, and that might always give you the same value. As soon you are introduce another variable at the stack that behavior might  change dramatically. To obtain [_pseudo random values_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) refer to the standard library facilities please.

Comment: @PrashanthRavichandar: Even if we assume that the compiler is not doing any funny business, and is translating your code to assembly in a straightforward manner, (that is, `a[-1]` simply accesses the value in memory directly preceding `a[0]`), it is not at all unlikely that you see 0 over and over again, since 0 is by far the most common value in memory. The compiler doesn't just insert random values in unused memory locations.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley And who's even to say that the memory location being accessed is even unused! It's almost like there's a term for behavior you can't reason about... what is it again....

Comment: @cdhowie: I don't know what that term is. It's not undefined behavior though, if that's what you're thinking. Because you can certainly reason about undefined behavior if you understand how your compiler works. Undefined behavior simply means that the language standard doesn't define the behavior. But there are other factors at play in the behavior of a piece of software than the language standard.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are correct in that with sufficient understanding of the compiler and it's inputs, you *might* predict undefined behavior. However, that understanding will be limited to that specific build of that specific version of that specific compiler. If you rely on that understanding, you will eventually be unpleasantly surprised when it suddenly changes on you when you don't expect it. You will also find that the compiler will choose to do *weird* things when it encounters undefined behavior. Trying to reason about undefined behavior is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` is an array `int a[N]`, then it is undefined behavior to use a subscript that would be out of bounds, i.e. smaller than `0` or bigger than `N-1` (e.g. `a[-1]`).

If however, `a` would be a function argument declared as array, or if a would be a pointer, a negative subscript could be legal, provided that it addresses an element in the bounds of an array.  In this case `a[-1]` would be perfectly valid and is equivalent to `*(a-1)`;

For example:

```
int arr[100];
int *a = arr+50;  
cout<<a[-1]<<endl;
```

or:

```
void f(int a[8]) {
    cout<<a[-1]<<endl;
}
...
f(&arr[50]);
```

This is guaranteed by the standard:

> **5.2.1/1:** A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have
>   the type “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have
>   unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is of type “T.”
>   (...) The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to
>   `*((E1)+(E2))`

Comment: The question states that `a` is an array and not a pointer to an array. The fact that he stats that he expects that `a[-1]` gives random values supports that interpretation.

Comment: Yes, true.  But if you'd define a function `void f(int a[8])`,  the parameter although being  declared as an array will be handled as a pointer, and you can then obtain the same consistent result as above:  https://ideone.com/Ds3SoI